# SQL to Criteria using propel

Tags: symfony1, criteria, propel

I have this sql:

```
SELECT link.ID, link.URL, link.ANCHOR, link.HOME, link.CREATED_AT 
FROM `link`, `linkcategory`
WHERE link.ID=linkcategory.LINK_ID
GROUP BY linkcategory.LINK_ID 
HAVING count(linkcategory.category_id) =(select count(*) from categoria)
```

And I'm trying to generate the criteria, this is the criteria that doesn't work:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin(self::ID, LinkcategoryPeer::LINK_ID);
$c->addAsColumn('catCount','(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CATEGORIA)');
$c->addGroupByColumn(LinkcategoryPeer::LINK_ID);
$having = $c->getNewCriterion(count(LinkcategoryPeer::CATEGORY_ID),$c->getColumnForAs('catCount'));
$c->addHaving($having); 
return self::doSelect($c);
```

The returning sql of this criteria is this one:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CATEGORIA) AS catCount 
FROM `link`, `linkcategory` 
WHERE link.ID=linkcategory.LINK_ID 
GROUP BY linkcategory.LINK_ID 
HAVING 1='(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CATEGORIA)'
```

I really don't know why the criteria convert the sql incorrectly. Anyone knows where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query. I don't remember how to perform a `link.*` using Propel. But I think the problem with `having` is that you are using the PHP count function insteand of the MySQL one.

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addSelectColumn(self::ID);
$c->addSelectColumn(self::URL);
$c->addSelectColumn(self::ANCHOR);
$c->addSelectColumn(self::HOME);
$c->addSelectColumn(self::CREATED_AT );

$c->addJoin(self::ID, LinkcategoryPeer::LINK_ID);
$c->addGroupByColumn(LinkcategoryPeer::LINK_ID);

$having = $c->getNewCriterion(
  'COUNT('.LinkcategoryPeer::CATEGORY_ID.')'),
  $c->getColumnForAs('catCount')
);
$c->addHaving($having);

return self::doSelect($c);
```